# For each and every ssh command asks for password, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ssh, subprocess

I am trying to execute the following code, which asks me password for each and every ssh command though I provide my password in the code. Can any one please tell me where I am doing mistake.  Thanks in advance

```
import signal
from subprocess import call, PIPE, Popen
from time import sleep
import os, pty
class SshCmd:

    socket = ''
    pid = 0
    password = None

    def __init__(self, password = None):
        if password:
            SshCmd.password = password

            # start agent
            devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
            call(['killall', 'ssh-agent'], stderr=devnull)
            process = Popen('/usr/bin/ssh-agent', stdout=PIPE, stderr=devnull)
            stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
            lines = stdout.splitlines()
            SshCmd.socket = lines[0].decode().split(';')[0].split('=')[1]
            SshCmd.pid = lines[1].decode().split(';')[0].split('=')[1]
            devnull.close()

            # unlock key
            pid, fd = pty.fork()
            if 0 == pid:
                # child adds key
                os.execve('/usr/bin/ssh-add', ['/usr/bin/ssh-add'], \
                    {'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': SshCmd.socket, 'SSH_AGENT_PID': SshCmd.pid})
            else:
                # parent send credentials
                cmsg = os.read(fd, 1024)
                os.write(fd, SshCmd.password.encode())
                os.write(fd, os.linesep.encode())
                cmsg = os.read(fd, 1024)
                if len(cmsg) <= 2:
                    os.waitpid(pid, 0)
                else:
                    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)

    def execve(self, path, args, env = {}):
        if not SshCmd.password:
            return
        pid = os.fork()
        if 0 == pid:
            env['SSH_AUTH_SOCK'] = SshCmd.socket
            env['SSH_AGENT_PID'] = SshCmd.pid
            os.execve(path, args, env)
        else:
            os.waitpid(pid, 0)

    def ssh(self, user, host, cmd, args = []):
        cmdLine = cmd
        for arg in args:
            cmdLine += ' '
            cmdLine += arg
        self.execve('/usr/bin/ssh',
                ['/usr/bin/ssh',
                '-o',
                'UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null',
                '-o',
                'StrictHostKeyChecking=false',
                '%(user)s@%(host)s' % {'user': user, 'host': host},
                cmdLine])

if '__main__' == __name__:
    other = SshCmd('passowrd')
    other.ssh('root', 'host', '/sbin/ifconfig')
    other.ssh('root', 'host', 'ping', ['-c', '5', 'localhost'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not making a mistake. In order to skip the password step, you need to pre-validate your request, you can do this by using the command `ssh-copy-id` first. which will store the credentials and allow connection through a key. You need to have a key first, which you can create with `ssh-keygen`

Note: these commands may change depending on the linux distribution.

Comment: That's the way to do it. Also notice: never ever store a password in plain text!